# Custom Filter in Django (1.3) Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

How to add a filter in Django Admin that should give a filtered result in the filters that appear on the right side of a model dashboard .

More clearly :

```
class County (models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 255, blank = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, blank = True)


class County_info (models.Model):
   county = models.ForeignKey(County)
   city  = models.CharField(max_length = 255, blank = True)
   state = models.CharField(max_length = 255, blank = True)
   ......
   ......
```

in my adim.py i have to show a filter for the model 'County_info' for the field 'county' that has the status 'Production'.

```
list_filter = ['county__name', ] # will Show all data in that table. I need onlt the data which has status= 'production'
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem few days ago, and I figured out it is only possible using 1.4 : [Admin filter documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter)